# SQLite query not working when trying to run the same query in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have a database of users purchase/sell of stocks and need to retrieve the data by summing all the shares for that specific user.

Ex: If I choose user_id = 7, it should return two rows, one with TESLA and one with Apple with the sums of the shares.

Database:
[image]

SQL queries I've tried include:

```
SELECT name,symbol,name,price,total, SUM(shares) 
FROM symbol 
WHERE user_id=7 
GROUP BY name,symbol,name,price,total
```

Returns: but it should just be two rows
[image]

Comment: At least one question will be answered if you show the *desired* output along with the *actual* output you got.

Comment: You asked the same question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70627396/i-cant-seem-to-translate-from-sql-to-postgresql-correctly-when-using-select-wh and you accepted an answer. The query that you post here is from the other answer that you did not accept and which is obviously wrong.

Comment: Yes, so I think the issue is putting the names in quotations as they are reserved words. It's a bit different in that I am now running into an issue with getting rid of duplicates and am trying to sum by stock name @forpas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is your grouping.

Consider the uniqueness of what you are grouping by and that is how many rows you will get returned.

With your `where` clause and grouping by `name,symbol,name,price,total` there are three unique rows.

Remove the `price` and `total` columns from the grouping and you will get your desired two rows, or include them in your query as sum'd columns.

eg.

```
SELECT name,symbol,name,SUM(shares) 
FROM symbol 
WHERE user_id=7 
GROUP BY name,symbol,name
```

Comment: I tried using your code, but I keep getting:Error in query: ERROR: column "symbol.price" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT name,symbol,name,price,total, SUM(shares)

Comment: updated to remove those columns as per my answer.